# BDD implementations in Java

Tags: java, prolog, theorem-proving, binary-decision-diagram

Anyone has suggestions for BDD (binary decision diagrams) implementations in Java (or one that provides Java bindings)? I found this page online: http://www.mancoosi.org/~abate/avalaible-bdd-libraries but not sure if it is out of date. Or does it make sense to just use a Prolog implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English wikipedia page provides a number of possible BDD packages in almost any famous programming language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram

I didn't tried it out, but JavaBDD can interface to CUDD which is one of the best BDD packages by now. http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/